# How to determine a character within a string in c++

Tags: c++, c

I have a variable named "String" that may have values like the following ones:

```
const char* String = "/v1/AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1/test/DSC_0188.JPG";
```

or

```
const char* String = "/auth/v1.0";
```

or

```
const char* String = "/v2/AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1/images?limit=1000&delimiter=/&format=xml";
```

Now I want to make sure whether or not "String" has the character 'v1'. Checking this has to be precise. I tried with strchr, but it's not quite accurate as it doesn't take 'v1' as one character, it rather takes 'v' and '1' as two separate characters. Moreover I can't use namepace std and library string, I can only use "string.h". Within these limitations how can I accurately check whether the variable "String" has a character 'v1'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to make sure whether or not "String" has the character 'v1'
>
> I can only use "string.h"

Then you probably want [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr). Also `v1` is not a character, it's a string.

---

Side note: why use `cstring` in C++ ? What kind of teacher is still calling it `string.h` ?!

Comment: It's not a teacher that's saying me to do it. I'm doing a project where we have limitations with using namespace std and library string along with some other libraries because of memory issue.

Answer (score 3):

`v1` is not character according to any alphabet. This is a proper string "v1" and as @cnicutar mentioned the c way to search for string in string is to use `strstr`. It is quite easy to use and runs [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which is also very fast (though for the kind of your string it is not that crucial).

I would advise you to:

- always name your variables starting small-caps (i.e. `String` -> `my_string`)
- declare your string as `const char[]`, no need to interfere with pointers, when you can avoid them. Declaring this as pointer might confuse you, that you dynamically allocated the memory for the string.